# Installation of Openstack on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, openstack

I am trying to setup Openstack on Ubuntu 12.04 but I am facing weird  issues installing some of the nova components.

I followed [this](https://fosskb.wordpress.com/2014/04/12/openstack-icehouse-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-single-machine-setup/) article for installing it

The following are the Nova packages not getting installed

```
vidyayug@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -y nova-conductor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nova-conductor
vidyayug@ubuntu:~$



vidyayug@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install nova-novncproxy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nova-novncproxy
```

i.e. two of the nova packages are not getting installed

```
vidyayug@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -y nova-api nova-cert nova-conductor nova-consoleauth nova-novncproxy nova-scheduler python-novaclient nova-compute nova-console
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nova-conductor
E: Unable to locate package nova-novncproxy
```

I tried to resolve the error by googling it but was not successful in resolving it. My installation is struck due to this.

I was able to setup Openstack Icehouse on server with Ubuntu 14.04 for POC purpose but the Actual Production Server  I want to setup Openstack is HP ProLiant DL 580 G5  is not supporting 14.04 version of ubuntu.

Please help me if there is any fix for this errors.

Comment: In 12.04 you will want to use the ubuntu cloud archive.  This is an extra package source. read more here:  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive    12.04 is no longer the latest LTS release though.  You should be using 14.04 now.

Comment: Hi Jeevan.. thanks for the comment. So do you mean for installing Open stack icechouse we have to go for Ubuntu 14.04 version.

Answer (score 0):

Go here to the Ubuntu Packages site to download Nova Compute:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nova-compute

Comment: Hi Kerry, Thanks for the quick reply. I have tried the link you have posted it here but i am still having issues.